# Scraping images in a dynamic, JavaScript webpage using Scrapy and Splash

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-splash

I am trying to **scrape** the link of a hi-res image from [this link](https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-hyundai-accent/bayramda-arabasiz-kalmaa/17753653) but the high-res version of the image can only be inspected upon clicking on the mid-sized link on the page, i.e after clicking *"Click here to enlarge the image"* (on the page, it's in Turkish).

Then I can inspect it with Chrome's "Developer Tools" and get the xpath/css selector. Everything is fine up to this point.

However, you know that in a JS page, you just can't type `response.xpath("//blah/blah/@src")` and get some data. I install Splash (with Docker pull) and configure my Scrapy `setting.py` files etc. to make it work *(this [YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VvFC93vAB7U) helped. no need to visit the link unless you wanna learn how to do it)*. ...and it worked on other JS webpages!

Just... I cannot pass this *"Click here to enlarge the image!"* thing and get the response. It gives me `null` response.

This is my code:

```py
import scrapy
#import json
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class TryMe(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'try_me'
    allowed_domains = ['arabam.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = ["https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-hyundai-accent/bayramda-arabasiz-kalmaa/17753653",
        ]

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, 
            callback=self.parse, 
            meta={'splash': {'endpoint': 'render.html', 'args': {'wait': 0.5}}})
            # yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse)  # this works too

    def parse(self, response):
        ## I can get this one's link successfully since it's not between js codes:
        #IMG_LINKS = response.xpath('//*[@id="js-hook-for-ing-credit"]/div/div/a/img/@src').get() 
        ## but this one just doesn't work:      
        IMG_LINKS = response.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img/@src").get()
        print(IMG_LINKS)  # prints null :(
        yield {"img_links":IMG_LINKS}  # gives the items: img_links:null
```

Shell command which I'm using:
`scrapy crawl try_me -O random_filename.jl`

Xpath of the link I'm trying to **scrape**:
`/html/body/div[7]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/img`

[Image of this Xpath/link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GogPp.jpg)

I actually can see the link I want on the **Network** tab of my **Developer Tools window** when I click to enlarge it but I don't know how to **scrape** that link from that tab.

**Possible Solution:** I also will try to get the whole garbled body of my response, i.e `response.text` and apply a **regular expression** (e.g start with `https://...` and ends with `.jpg`) to it. This will definitely be looking for a needle in a haystack but it sounds quite practical as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to find the main image link. I checked out the page, it is inside the one of meta element:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://arbstorage.mncdn.com/ilanfotograflari/2021/06/23/17753653/3c57b95d-9e76-42fd-b418-f81d85389529_image_for_silan_17753653_1920x1080.jpg">
```

Which you can get with

```
>>> response.css('meta[itemprop=image]::attr(content)').get()
'https://arbstorage.mncdn.com/ilanfotograflari/2021/06/23/17753653/3c57b95d-9e76-42fd-b418-f81d85389529_image_for_silan_17753653_1920x1080.jpg'
```

You don't need to use splash for this. If I check the website with splash, arabam.com gives permission denied error. I recommend not using splash for this website.

For a better solution for all images, You can parse the javascript. Images array loaded with js right here in the source.

[image]

To reach out that javascript try:

```
  response.css('script::text').getall()[14]
```

This will give you the whole javascript string containing images array. You can parse it with built-in libraries like js2xml.

Check out how you can use it here https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml. If still have questions, you can ask. Good luck

Comment: 1) I parsed your last code (the one with `[14]`) with `js2xml.parse(...)`  2) `js2xml.pretty_print(...)` it and found the path to the desired `jpg`.  3) Extracted the links with xpath selector: `parsed.xpath("//object/property[@name='src']/string/text()")`  4) Viola! Thanks a lot!   PS: I have also solved it with a specific regex pattern  but I think yours can be applied to any webpage when you just cannot find any logical string pattern on the image links.

Comment: Exactly! If the page is loaded with inline css you can parse javascript strings, otherwise, splash is helpful. Glad it helped )